# How to convert Java Regex to JS regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Java Regex:

```
String regex = "(?i)^[\\w.-][\\+\\w.-]*+@[\\w.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$";
  Pattern  pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("santo+abc@gmail.com");
 System.out.println(matcher.matches());
```

JS Regex:

```
 var regex = /^[\w.-][\w\+.-]*+@[\w.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i;
```

But JS regex is not a valid expression. Not sure what I am missing here. Please guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
/^[\w.-][\w\+.-]*@[\w.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i
```

I removed the `+` after the `*`, because JavaScript doesn't support possessive quantifier.

You can try this regex here: https://regex101.com/r/FmUF5M/1

Answer (score 1):

`*+` is a possessive quantifier. It’s like `*`, but fails the match if it has to match less than what’s available to it. Since `@` doesn’t match `[\w\+.-]` anyway, though, you can just replace it with `*`.

```
var regex = /^[\w.-][\w\+.-]*@[\w.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i;
```

Also, don’t use this regex to validate e-mail addresses; it’s incorrect. See [Regex validation of email addresses according to RFC5321/RFC5322](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992403/regex-validation-of-email-addresses-according-to-rfc5321-rfc5322) for a correct one.