# How to check if input looks like an email address and then activate submit button?

Tags: javascript

I use the following code to check if all form fields are not empty before the submit button is activated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function checkForm() {
                var cansubmit = false;
                $('form input[type="text"]').each(function (index, element) {
                    if (element.value == "") {
                        cansubmit = true;
                    }
                });
                document.getElementById("uploadButton").disabled = cansubmit;
            }
        </script>
```

How can I edit this code so it checks if the email field contains an email address before the submit button is activated?

**UPDATE**

I changed the code to this and it seems to work. It checks if it contains `@` (and not as the first symbol) and `.` (and not as the third symbol).

**Is this a logical code or should it be easier?**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function checkForm() {
                var cansubmit = false;
                $('form input[type="text"]').each(function (index, element) {
                    if (element.value == "") {
                        cansubmit = true;
                    }
                });
                $('form input[type="email"]').each(function (index, element) {
                    if (element.value.indexOf("@") <= 0) {
                        cansubmit = true;
                    }
                    else if (element.value.indexOf(".") <= 2) {
                        cansubmit = true;
                    }
                });
                document.getElementById("uploadButton").disabled = cansubmit;
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26989421/2930038) answer to validate email address:

```
if ((element.value == "" && element.type != "email") || (element.type == "email" && !/([!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~-]+(\.[!#-'*+/-9=?A-Z^-~-]+)*|"([]!#-[^-~ \t]|(\\[\t -~]))+")@([0-9A-Za-z]([0-9A-Za-z-]{0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?(\.[0-9A-Za-z]([0-9A-Za-z-]{0,61}[0-9A-Za-z])?)*|\[((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])){3}|IPv6:((((0|[1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,3}):){6}|::((0|[1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,3}):){5}|[0-9A-Fa-f]{0,4}::((0|[1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,3}):){4}|(((0|[1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,3}):)?(0|[1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,3}))?::((0|[1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,3}):){3}|(((0|[1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,3}):){0,2}(0|[1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,3}))?::((0|[1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,3}):){2}|(((0|[1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,3}):){0,3}(0|[1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,3}))?::(0|[1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,3}):|(((0|[1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,3}):){0,4}(0|[1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,3}))?::)((0|[1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,3}):(0|[1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,3})|(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])(\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9]{2}|[1-9]?[0-9])){3})|(((0|[1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,3}):){0,5}(0|[1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,3}))?::(0|[1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,3})|(((0|[1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,3}):){0,6}(0|[1-9A-Fa-f][0-9A-Fa-f]{0,3}))?::)|(?!IPv6:)[0-9A-Za-z-]*[0-9A-Za-z]:[!-Z^-~]+)])/.test(element.value))) {
```

Comment: See my updated answer which seems to work. Is this a logical code or should it be easier?

Comment: FYI the regex provided does **ABSOLUTELY NOT** validate an email address. It just validates a very strict subset of email addresses, for example the following *valid* email addresses are rejected: `my+email@example.com`, `email(comment)@example.com`, `".John..Doe"@example.com`, `#email@example.com`, moreover it also prevents the use of long gTLDs so `john.doe@example.company` fails because `company` is not 2-3 characters long.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of `<input type="email">` and `inputElement.validity` to check if the input is valid. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState)