# Validating E-Mail Addresses and printing valid ones in Java

Tags: java, validation, exception, try-catch

I'm trying to practice exception handling in java, and doing so by running a few (in)valid e-mail addresses and validating them. So far, I'm able to print out the non validated ones, but I'm looking for a way to also print the one who is validated. If I println in the try block, the john.doe.gmail.com address prints out as being validated for some reason.

Could someone suggest something?

```
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;

public class AdressChecker  {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String toTest[] =
          {"john.doe@gmail.com", "john.doe.gmail.com", "john.doe@", "@gmail.com"};

    System.out.println("Addresses to be verified");
    for (String x : toTest)
      System.out.println(x);
    for (String s : toTest) {
      try {
        InternetAddress emailAddr = new InternetAddress(s);                    
        emailAddr.validate();                        
      } catch (AddressException ex) {
        System.out.println(s + " is not a valid E-Mail Address.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Working now. The output is:

```
Addresses to be verified
john.doe@gmail.com
john.doe.gmail.com
john.doe@
@gmail.com
john.doe@gmail.com is a valid E-Mail Address.
john.doe.gmail.com is not a valid E-Mail Address.
john.doe@ is not a valid E-Mail Address.
@gmail.com is not a valid E-Mail Address.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to print the email after `emailAddr.validate()` line check this :

```
for (String s : toTest) 
        {
            try
             {
                 InternetAddress emailAddr = new InternetAddress(s);                    
                 emailAddr.validate();
                 System.out.println(s + " is a valid E-Mail Address.");                        
             }    
            catch (AddressException ex)
             {
             System.out.println(s + " is not a valid E-Mail Address.");
              }

       }
```

Comment: then it might be a problem with java mail API, could you try by using only john.doe.gmail.com address, whether it is validating or throwing any exception.

Comment: Because it's valid `InternetAddress`. You need other method to check e-mails. For this simple case, regex may do the job: `^\w+(\.\w+){0,1}@\w+\.\w+$` @Boricode

Comment: With Java Mail API 1.5, only `john.doe@gmail.com` is marked as valid. No need for a regex.

Answer (score 0):

You could add your `println` statement after `.validate()` call.
Since it will raise an exception when the address is invalid, the `println` call will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

With the [`InternetAddress.validate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/mail/internet/InternetAddress.html#validate%28%29) method you do **not** check the validity of **only** email addresses. The syntax in [RFC 822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt) (section 6.1) is much broader than the addresses we generally use today as email addresses. Think about tools like `ssh` that also take internet addresses as parameter and they look like: `user@localhost`. This passes the `InternetAddress` validation because it is a valid Internet address. And can be a valid email address as well in certain network scenarios.

So you will have answers like this?

```
Addresses to be verified
john@gmail is a valid E-Mail Address
john@gmail.coooooooooooooom is a valid E-Mail Address
john+1@gmail.com is a valid E-Mail Address
john+2@gmail.com is a valid E-Mail Address
john+3000@gmail.com is a valid E-Mail Address
```

It depends **very much** of your scenarios in your application. Sometimes you want to:

- avoid aliases (`john+1@gmail.com` is the same as `john@gmail.com` for Gmail)
- avoid non existent top level domains (`cooooooom`) (until the [new generic top level domains](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/) really come into existence)
- etc.

If your email addresses have to be only valid email addresses that are used on the Web (like having domain and subdomain), I recommend using a regular expression. For this you have plenty answers:

- [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)
- [Java regex email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204680/java-regex-email)
- or [blog entry](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-email-address-with-regular-expression/) with explanations

Comment: I would recommend using the validator from the [Apache Commons Validator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/) framework.  There was only one case that the validator didn't work for, and it is actually explained in the javadoc of the validator.

Comment: There is also a [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html) for validating [Email Addresses](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/impl/EmailValidator.html).