# NullPointerException on validating email

Tags: java, android, android-studio, junit, junit4

I am writing a unit test to check the email validation logic. The logic is throwing null pointer exception when you run the test. But it works fine with emulator. Can someone help me solving this?

```
public static String validate(String email, String password) {
        if (email == null || email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            return "Enter valid email address";
        }
        if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 4) {
            return "Password should be between 4 and 10 alphanumeric characters";
        }
        return null;
}
```

Below is my unit test.

```
@Test
public void validateShouldReturnMessageIfYouPassAnInvalidEmail() throws Exception {
    String validateMessage = LoginService.validate("abcdef", "password");
    assertEquals("Enter valid email address", validateMessage);
}
```

The error I am getting is,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.tryout.hemanth.expensetracker.service.LoginService.validate(LoginService.java:11)
```

Comment: what is inside `LoginService` ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna i have a validate method which does the validation. As I have added my login in question.

Comment: show us your method LoginService.validate

Comment: If that's the line where you get the NPE, it looks like `android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS` is `null`.

Comment: @Axel Yes. Can't I use android.util in unit testing?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto i have updated the question

Comment: have you tried using regex or removing that line ? and is it working well ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna without android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches() it works fine

Comment: Do you have API Level 8 available when running JUnit? To be honest, I don't know how JUnit integrates with your Android build environment, so this is just a guess...

Comment: @HemanthGowda yah ok then.. I added an answer in detail with a link. Hope you will find that helpful It should be working.

Comment: @Axel But the same code works fine with emulator. I don't know why android is null when i run it through Junit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()` exists since API level 8, May be your emulator is prior than this.

So I suggest Adding custom `EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN` string as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5296201/5067493) answer and check it like

```
if (email == null || email.isEmpty() || !EMAIL_ADDRESS_PATTERN.matcher(email).matches()){
     return "Enter valid email address";
}
```

Comment: But the same code works fine with emulator. I don't know why android is null when i run it through Junit.

Comment: Are you sure you are using JUNIT latest like 4. Or your device's API level is compatible ? [see](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/testing-support-library/index.html#ajur-junit) the requirements and rules of testing.

Comment: This issue is not because of emulator but the android sdk version. In my case Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS works as expected below version 28 but it suddenly returns null on version 29.

Answer (score 24):

Use **PatternsCompat** instead of **Patterns**

Comment: Why PatternsCompat works? The pattern's string is the same

Comment: Interesting `PatternsCompat` belongs in `androidx` which is newer

Comment: `PatternsCompat` made my day

Answer (score 1):

In case if **Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS** doesn't match with your requirements,

create your **own regex pattern** for better use.

Please refer to [this EMAIL ADDRESS regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8204716/2853544) for instance.

Comment: Because the regex is complex does't mean it is not right. What if you have to validate an email your simpler regex does not cover?

Comment: @Kaizie Yes you are right. I mean you can customize you validation as you want. Complex or simple is based on you business logic

Answer (score 0):

try this, this is working for me :

```
fun isValidEmail(email:String?):Boolean {
return when{
    email.isNullOrEmpty()-> false
    else-> PatternsCompat.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
}
```

}

Test cases:

```
 @Test
fun validate_email_invalid() {
    val email = "a"
    Assert.assertEquals(false, isValidEmail(email))
}
```