# How to check if only one '@' symbol in email address using regex in java?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regex in java to validate the email address. It should contain one uppercase one lowercase one digit only one @ symbol followed by '.'.So far i could only create this,

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*@)(?=.*\.).+$
```

scenarios like these

abC.8@gmailcom this address should return false

abC8@@gmail.com this also should return  false

But the above regex returns true for all these scenarios.Could anyone help me correct this regex?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java regex email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204680/java-regex-email)

Comment: Not quite what you're asking, but ... if you look around a bit, you're sure to find a regular expression that matches valid email addresses.

Comment: No domain name in email ? That's unheard of.

Comment: To clearify. It should contain. Maxium of one uppercase letter, maximum one lowercase letter, one digit?

Comment: @kkflf it should contain atleast one uppercase lowercase and one digit and maximum of one '@' character.but the above regex allows more than one '@' character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a negative lookahead to the regex to avoid 2 @

```
(?!.*@.*@)
```

But you could also make the last part of the regex more explicit, so that a double @ wouldn't match

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[\w.]+@[\w.]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Or to allow more than just the [a-zA-Z0-9_] word characters and dots, but still excluding the whitespaces:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])[^\s@]+@[^\s@]*\.[^\s@.]{2,}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Validating emails with regexes is something that others have done before. According to [emailregex.com](http://emailregex.com/), this is the java regex for emails:

```
(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])
```

They claim that it works 99.99% of the time.

The other page, [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) provides lots of other regex, starting with this simple one:

```
^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$
```

I.e. some valid characters, then the `@`, then the domain name.
The step by step they show you how to build a regex that matches the [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4).

Regarding making sure there's only one `@`, you can go with this:

```
^[^@]*@[^@]*$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with below, It is not strict though but ignore your patterns which you've mentioned in question,

```
(?:[a-zA-Z\.\d]{1})+@\.com
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nAU1yK/2/)

Comment: Failing to consider all other top level domains

Answer (score 0):

I tried taking in consideration how my email should be and step by step i reached this conclusion, it will always accept '@' only in a specific part of the mail otherwise it won't be considered valid

```
^[^@,:; \t\r\n]+@[^@,:; \t\r\n]+\.[^@,:; \t\r\n]+$
```