# using regex in java for validate email

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to validate a certain subset of the e-mail format with regular expressions, but what I've tried so far doesn't quite work. This is my regex (Java):

```
boolean x = l.matches(
    "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\\\+]+(\\\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@\"\n" +"+ \"[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$"
);
```

Thse are the conditions that the string has to match:

- Mail domain is from the list:

  > - www.fightclub.uk
  > - www.fightclub.lk
  > - www.fightclub.sa
  > - www.fightclub.cc
  > - www.fightclub.jp
  > - www.fightclub.se
  > - www.fightclub.xy
  > - www.fightclub.gi
  > - www.fightclub.rl
  > - www.fightclub.ss
- username has 3 to 6 characters(only lowercase English letters and numbers)

examples:

`sonia6@fightclub.com` is `valid`

`am@fightclub2.lk` is `invalid`

Comment: *..username has 3 to 6 characters(only lowercase English letters and numbers)..* -> `[a-z0-9]{6}` will do it for you. Rest you didn't provide the information for other half.

Comment: See [*Java regex email*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204680/java-regex-email).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i tried with it also.but i faild.  can u show me correct code.i am new for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
^[a-z0-9]{3,6}@fightclub\.(?:uk|lk|sa|cc|jp|se|xy|gi|rl|ss)$
```

1. `^` indicates start of string
2. `[a-z0-9]{3,6}` lowercase letters or number with length 3-6 characters
3. followed by `@fightclub`
4. followed by a period `\.`
5. followed by a list of domains `(?:` indicate that it's a non-capturing group. All your domain extensions are listed here.
6. `$` indicates end of string

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/rYYXYA/1

Comment: i got `valid` to `am@fightclub2.lk` also.can u help me

Comment: @Intern I missed initial `^` and last `$`. Check regex again now. Also check the demo.

Comment: no friend.i got `am@fightclub2.lk` is `valid`.but should be invalid

Comment: question (too lazy to check): does regex101 support Java's idiom of regular expressions?

Comment: @Intern I've created this online compilation of code with exacts same case. https://ideone.com/2X47NH . Its returning false.

Comment: i tried with this code `boolean x=arr[j].matches("^[a-z0-9]{3,6}@fightclub\\.(?:uk|lk|sa|cc|jp|se|xy|gi|rl|ss)$");
            if (x == false) {
                System.out.println("INVALID");
            //return false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("VALID");
                //return true;
            }`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I haven't encountered any situation until now where it won't work with java. However, you're right, this flavour isn't mentioned officially on their website.

Comment: @Intern I'm not sure what's there in `arr[j]`. Please try it once after hardcoding the value like: `boolean x= "am@fightclub2.lk".matches("^[a-z0-9]{3,6}@fightclub\\.(?:uk|lk|sa|cc|‌​jp|se|xy|gi|rl|ss)$"‌​);`

Comment: @Intern or including the  tested address in the message - the expression seems prefect for me. And tested on [RegEx Planet](http://fiddle.re/nzx1yd)

Comment: you are correct mate.false is mine.so sorry and you are really great man.thank you very much