# How to match any amount of characters in a Java Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

So I've been tasked with writing a pattern detector that can recognize emails. So I need to be able to read the email names of anybody. I have the issue of reading the domain of the email, I just need to know how to read the actual name of the email. For further explanation of what I actually need to check for see bolded portion below.

**randomemail88**@whatever.com
**bad3mai99l**@hop.man.edu

This is what I have so far, and it is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

```
patterns.add("[.]+@[a-z]+\\.[a-z]+\\.*[a-z]*");
```

Comment: What about `([^@\s]+)@(\S+)`? The first group is the local-part and the second is the domain

Comment: You mean [`^[^@]+`](https://regex101.com/r/NQ0ttR/1)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204680/java-regex-email ?