# Regex to find the @ sign within a string

Tags: java, regex

I need help with my regex so it can find if there is an @ sign within the string I'm searching.

```java
import java.util.regex.*;
public class OnlineNewspaperSubscription extends NewspaperSubscription
{
    public void setAddress(String a)
    {

         address = a;

        // Creating a pattern from regex
        Pattern pattern
            = Pattern.compile("@*");

        // Get the String to be matched
        String stringToBeMatch = a;

        // Create a matcher for the input String
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringToBeMatch);

       if(matcher.matches())
        {
            super.rate = 9;

        }
       else
        {
            super.rate = 0;
            System.out.println("Need an @ sign");
        }

    }

}
```

I should be able to tell whether this string is an email address or not.

Comment: Why use a regex? You can use `String#contains()` or `String#indexOf()`

Comment: Change regex from `"@*"` to `"@"` and change `matches()` to `find()`.

Comment: I thought regex would be easier to get this in but I'll try the indexOf

Comment: Partly duplicate of [Difference between matches() and find() in Java Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4450045/5221149)

Comment: `I should be able to tell whether this string is an email address or not` with the @, yeah sure thing.

Comment: "I should be able to tell whether this string is an email address or not."

is Select client.name, "@" from Clients an email address?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a regular expression to find the index of `'@'` in a `String`; use [`String.indexOf(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-) (passing a `char`). Like,

```
int p = a.indexOf('@');
if (p > -1) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use regex for this, it is an overkill. You can just use the method [`contains()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) from the String class available from java 1.5 (if I remember correctly). This method does actually use internally `indexOf()`.

```
System.out.println("Does not contain :" + "Does not contain".contains("@"));
System.out.println("Does cont@in :" + "Does not cont@in".contains("@"));
```

**output:**

```
Does not contain @:false
Does contain @:true
```

**Notes:**

> If what you want to do is validate the format of an email address,
>   checking the presence of an `@` is not sufficient, I would recommend
>   using a regex for this.
>
> **Example**: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8204716/8794221