# Make sure the regex used in this method call cannot lead to denial of service

Tags: java, sonarqube

In the below code SonarQube suggest to avoid catastrophic backtracking
Please suggest how to resolve this denial of service by SonarQube

```
public static boolean ValidEmailAddress(String email)
{
    final String ePattern = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
    java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(ePattern);
    java.util.regex.Matcher m = pattern.matcher(email);
    return m.matches();
}
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8204716/16688813