# how to validate email in javafx TextField?

Tags: regex, scenebuilder, javafx-11

**GOAL:**

I'm trying to validate the user's email address as he/she types.

I'm just using simple regex because I don't want to use any external library. Also if use the regex like in here [regex email for java](http://emailregex.com/) I'm encountering error `PatternSyntaxException` that's why I prefer simple regex for now.

So I put the `TextFormatter` and `UnaryOperator` inside the initialize method.

```
    @FXML
public void initialize()
{

    //1. USE UNARY FIRST TO MAKE FILTER BEFORE USING TEXTFORMATTER
    UnaryOperator <TextFormatter.Change> filterEmail = (change ->{
          
        if(change.getControlNewText().matches("^(.+)@(.+)$*"))
        {
                lblEmailError.setVisible(false);
                txtEmailAdd.setBorder(null);
                return change;
                
        }
            
        
        else
        {
            lblEmailError.setText("Invalid Email");
            lblEmailError.setVisible(true);
            txtEmailAdd.setBorder(new Border(new BorderStroke(Color.RED, BorderStrokeStyle.SOLID, new CornerRadii(3), new BorderWidths(2), new Insets(-2))));
            return null;
        }
        
        
    });
    
    TextFormatter <String> tf = new TextFormatter<String>(filterEmail);
    txtEmailAdd.setTextFormatter(tf);
   
    
}
```

But as long as the FXML loads I can't type anymore in the TextField and can't be edited anymore. I can't type anything. Maybe there is something wrong with my condition or I'm wrong putting it inside the initialize method.

[image]

I'm lost. I have already dug the web on how to validate email in java using regex.
like this [Java regex email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204680/java-regex-email)

I'm also using SceneBuilder to build the fxml. Any help will do thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `".*(?:@.*)?"` if you need a pattern to validate live input. Then use `".+@.+"` to validate the final input value.

Comment: I tried to use `".*(?:@.*)?"` but it allows double @ or invalid emails. I don't know how to validate using `".+@.+"` for the final value. My goal here is to check the `TextField` for invalid format emails while the user is typing.

Comment: Yes, and your regex would also allow that.

Comment: Yes, so can you point me in the right direction how to achieve what I want?

Comment: [How can I validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/3832970) and https://emailregex.com/

Comment: If you need to avoid multiple `@`, you can try this: `[^@]+(?:@[^@]*)?` for live matching and `[^@]+@[^@]+` for final validation. What are the other cases in which it doesn't work? @lelouch