# How could i format my regex, to validate an email with multiple domains, like jane@student.edu.au?

Tags: javascript, regex

i am using this regex

```
const emailRegex = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[A-Za-z]+$/);
```

but after i put .au, it considers it an incorrect email

Comment: Similar question with good answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204680/java-regex-email

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204680/java-regex-email with good answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you can specify the number of characters ?

```js
const emailRegex = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})+$/);
```

like so

```js
const emailRegex = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})+$/);

let matches = 'john.doe@domail.au'.match(emailRegex);

console.log(email);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const rgx = /\b\w+@\w[.\w]+\.\w+\b/g;
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/0A2f0L/1)

| Segment | Description |
| --- | --- |
| ``` \b\w+@ ``` | A non-word char to the left and to the right is one or more words, then a literal `@` |
| ``` \w[.\w]+ ``` | A word, then either a dot `.` or a word multiple times in any order. |
| ``` .\w+\b ``` | Next is a dot `.` followed by one or more words and ending with a word on the left and a non-word on the right. |

Word characters included under the `\w` meta sequence are:

- Upper `A` to `Z` and lower `a` to `z` case letters
- Digits `0` to `9`
- Underscore `_`

```js
const str = `
  user@mail.com
  user@sub.domain.net
  user@abc
  user@
  @mail.com
  `;
  
const rgx = /\b\w+@\w[.\w]+\.\w+\b/g;

console.log(str.match(rgx));
```